# Get Current Script Name While Was Calling from Another Script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, sh, ksh

In KornShell (ksh), I have a script that calls a list of scripts. The callee script needs to know its file name, so that it can generate unique configuration (or anything should be unique).

The problem is variable `$0` always points to the caller script. For example, we have two scripts:

caller.sh:

```
. callee.sh
```

callee.sh:

```
echo $0
```

When I execute caller.sh, the callee.sh print "caller.sh", not "callee.sh". So how can I get the script file name of current running script?

The script is running on AIX servers, so bash is not available all the time.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are sourcing callee.sh, i.e. `. callee.sh`.

So if you can just execute callee.sh (and you don't need environment variables that are set in callee.sh to be active in caller.sh,) change your caller scritpt to

```
#!/bin/ksh
callee.sh
```

I hate to say it, but I think the ksh people would say 'Working as designed'.

Comment: The reason I source the `callee.sh` is I need to call the function in `callee.sh` from `caller.sh`. Finally I pass the file name to `callee.sh`, not getting it from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Following command in callee.sh script worked for me.

```
echo $(basename ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})
```